# dynamically added usercontrol doesnt make use of css styling

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, webmethod

I have a webmethod which I use in added a user control to my web page via jQuery ajax function. This works fine and i can see the changes in my database, I can also see the UI updating, however the new control should be rendered in the UI as an accordion when added to the div, but instead it just renders it plain as if it is not using the CSS file.

**ASP.NET**

```
<div runat="server" id="dvProjects" class="dvProjectAccordion dvAccordion">
</div>
```

**WebMethod**

```
     [WebMethod]
        public string LoadProjectControl(UserProject addedProject)
        {
            using (Page page = new Page())
            {
                ProjectControl projectUserControl = (ProjectControl)page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ProjectControl.ascx");
                projectUserControl.Project = addedProject;
                projectUserControl.CreateProjectControl();
                using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    page.Controls.Add(projectUserControl);
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
                    return writer.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

**jQuery**

function AddUserProject() {
    var projectDialog = $('.dvEditExhibition');
    var projectName = projectDialog.find('.txtProjectName').val();
    var projectDescription = projectDialog.find('.txtProjectDescription').val();

    var project= JSON.stringify({
        'projectId': "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        'projectName': projectName,
        'projectDescription': projectDescription
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PresentationService.asmx/AddUserProject",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: project,
        success: function(response) {
            var data = response.d;
            console.log(data);
            var dvProjects = $('.dvProjectAccordion');
            dvProjects.append(data);
            $(".dvAccordion").accordion("refresh");
        },
        error: function(response) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We need to see the output HTML and the CSS, not the server control and WebMethod.

Comment: You may have to refresh or reset the accordion to let it know that a new element has arrived as accordion plugins add classes for styling when initialized.

Comment: Usually accordions and the like are wired in on document load, as the document has already loaded, it won't get wired in. You'll need to rebind the returned HTML to get everything to work. You need to post the front end code really, as that's where the issue lies.

Comment: @Tim updated with my front end code

Comment: @anpsmn updated with jquery code, is that where i do the refresh ?

Comment: In you success function, after the other stuff, add the code that you call to bind the accordion in the first place, and it should pick up the change?

Comment: @Tim i have done that, updated my code on here, that doesn't seem to do it

Comment: replace class name with div id in the success function where you make a call to bind the accordion.

Comment: @ifelabolz If you are already initializing the accordion on document ready then all you need is on success just [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh) the accordion to recompute the height. I have assumed that you are using jquery ui accordion.

Comment: @anpsmn i do have one more question though, how come when i refresh the page, the newly added control disappears, is this a view state issue and how do i solve this?

Comment: @ifelabolz when you refresh the page how do display the list? There must be a url which fetches you the project list. and check if new project is added to db.